# RabbitConnectionFactoryBean and CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-amqp

I can't find a mechanism in spring-rabbitMQ to use CachingConnectionFactory with SSL using RabbitConnectionFactoryBean  . what is the best way to provide SSL support for CachingConnectionFactory preferably using XML.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the results from the factory bean in a `CachingConnectionFactory`...

```
<bean id="rabbitFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" connection-factory="rabbitFactory" host="localhost" />
```

The `<rabbit/>` namespace creates a `CachingConnectionFactory` or you can declare it as a `<bean/>` and inject the rabbit factory with a `<constructor-arg/>`.